# Macro exports date column to csv as numeric value rather than dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, csv

The following code has achieved what I require except that the date `[cell B2]` is exported as as five digit numeric value rather than dd/mm/yyyy.

How to I amend the code to force `B2` to export as `dd/mm/yyyy`?

```
Sub Export_CSV()

    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim WB1 As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook



    Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

    Set WB2 = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    WB2.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues



    MyFileName = "XeroImport"
    FullPath = WB1.Path & "\" & MyFileName

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If MsgBox("Data copied to " & WB1.Path & "\" & MyFileName & vbCrLf & _
    "Warning: Files in directory with same name will be overwritten!!", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".csv" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".csv"
    With WB2
        .SaveAs Filename:=FullPath, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close True
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If **B2** shows:

[image]

Just before the `.SaveAs`, include these lines:

```
Dim s As String
s = Range("B2").Text
Range("B2").Value = "'" & Format(s, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: `Range().Text` will return the cell value as it is formatted. So if the cell shows "01/01/2015" it will return a string holding exactly that. `Range("B2").Value = "'" & Range("B2").Text` will be enough. :)